# Adjective-Noun vs Noun-が-Adjective

Tags: grammar, adjectives, relative-clauses

What is the difference between the two:

> - 高｛たか}い値段｛ねだん｝レストラン
> - 値段{ねだん｝が高{たか｝いレストラン

In other words, what is the difference between:

> - adjective-noun
> - noun-が-adjective

Another example would be this:

> - ボブは魚｛さかな｝が好き｛すき｝だ
> - ボブは好き｛すき｝魚｛さかな｝だ

I was reading http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/adjectives which uses the first form in these examples, but it also says you can modify a noun just by placing an i-adjective before it, and Google Translate gives me the same translations for both forms.

Comment: What's the difference... One phrase is plainly wrong, the other is correct.

Comment: I chuckled when I read your second example: the latter half isn't grammatical, but it _almost_ says _"Bob is a liked fish (i.e. a fish that I like)."_  :)

Comment: Lol, well I'm just starting out with grammar, so my made-up examples probably don't make sense, I'm just wondering why this is so.

Comment: 「値段が高い」 in 「値段が高いレストラン」 is a relative clause, no? Literally... "restaurant whose price is high"

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of the scope of your question, so let us know if Yuuichi's and my answers don't fully address what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand upon Yuuichi's answer, the difference is one of nuance and emphasis, and of the grammatical requirements of the construction, much as in English.

- **赤{あか}い車{くるま}**​で行{い}きます。
  We will go in a **red car**.
- 行{い}く**車{くるま}**​は**赤{あか}い**です。
  The **car** that we will go in is **red**.

Japanese is a bit more flexible than English when it comes to what terms are allowed to directly modify other terms.  We can say 行{い}く車{くるま} in Japanese (literally *"goes car"*, or depending on context, *"will be going car"*), but in English, relative clauses modifying nouns like this require grammatical words to tie things together: *"the car **that** goes"*.

Answer (score 1):

Adjective-Noun is a noun phrase like 高い値段、好きな魚.

Noun-が-Adjective is a sentence or modifies noun like 魚が好きだ, 値段が高いレストラン.